# closing space between content and body with css

Tags: css, css-float

in my web page  top right(see in attached image ) there is a space between content(background image) and body
i want to fill this space with image.i want to load image to all that space.I want to close that space.I give margin,padding-left but it does not close that space

```
 .wrapper  {
       width:100%;
         margin:-5px;
      }
```

what should i do

[image]

Comment: Might want to run the code through a HTML validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using Chrome Developer tools, you will quickly see that the space comes from the CSS margin attribute of your `<div class="wrapper">`. Please see the print screen below.

In the print screen, the space has disappeared because div.wrapper has no longer a margin.

[image]

**EDIT:**
The background picture has a transparent border itself. You can see this if you open your picture with a graphic program.

[image]

Best solution would be to remove the border with a graphic program because then, you are sure how you set your picture at a precise pixel position.

If you would like to pull the picture to the left in order to hide the border as quick solution, then you have to pull it left and at the same time stretch it slightly, e.g.

```
.wrapper {
   width: 101%;    /* <<<< a bit wider to hide at right */
   margin: -5px;   /* <<<< pull to hide at left */
   padding: 0
}
```

Like this, the border disappears left and right.

**EDIT 2:**

With `width: 101%`, scroll borders may appear. To get rid of them, use CSS `overflow-x: hidden`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x